# Migrate localhost (WAMP) EE install

Tags: migration, localhost

I have an EE site configured via WAMP on my local computer-- that pretty much mirrors the site's production environment-- and I'm about to perform a clean OS install and am wondering what might be the easiest way to recover/restore my current EE site configuration to a clean WAMP install? I plan to copy entire WAMP directory, with all my sites in the "www" directory, and presumably any related configuration files. Has anyone performed this sort of migration before who could offer some guidance? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://flowingmotion.jojordan.org/2013/07/19/12-steps-to-rebuild-your-wamp-server-without-losing-your-data/

This seems generally useful. Make sure you reinstall the **same** version of WAMP. Things like your config files and your entire web root are the most important to back up. Make sure you know all of your users and passwords. You can't just make a backup folder and restore it; WAMP does stuff in the Windows registry and port configs when it installs so it can open up; Make sure you install it with the same configuration (did you change the default install folder??).

Lastly, of course you need to do a full database dump.

And honestly, if you are duplicating in production, all you really need to do is make sure you install the same version of WAMP with the same configuration and set the same users and passwords (and don't forget your CONFIG FILES! think virtual host settings). If you have a good development to production work flow, this should be a breeze! When in doubt, **back it up**.

Comment: thanks for your response- I will check out the link you provided. As far as the EE install in concerned, I'm assuming that once WAMP is installed and the proper config files are modified along with the EE database imported, I should just be able to copy over the EE install directory into 'www' no? i.e. I shouldn't need to actually reinstall EE itself, correct?

Comment: You **just** want to duplicate your database, your web root (the directory you get when you go to 127.0.0.1 / localhost), and your apache config files. Ideally you also want to copy your PHP config files (if you've changed them). This doesn't apply exactly to a Windows environment, but I've adapted this person's scripts into a complex backup solution for major production appliances, and successfully restored appliances on new instances after disasters: https://github.com/jasongrimes/lamp-backup I recommend reviewing it for general learning purposes.

Comment: Oh, to answer your commment question, **yes**. If your new WAMP instance is installed with duplicate configuration and you have your config files (virtual hosts, etc...) copied over and your database imported and user/password configured ... yup! Just copy your web root to your new WAMP instance and you should be rolling right out. How are you accomplishing "pretty much mirrors the site's production environment"? With containers, version control, etc.. it's so easy these days to duplicate environments... just curios!

Comment: thanks again for your assistance-- I'm now fully up and running on my fresh OS install (Windows 10) and after duplicating the WAMP install, importing the database, etc. I was having issues with a "500 Internal Server Error" when attempting to log into EE admin. I realized that removing my existing `.htaccess` file solved the issue, although I have no idea why it might be creating a problem on the new OS. It is as follows: `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L] ` -- any ideas what might be going on here?

Comment: Ah never mind-- just forgot to enable the Apache `rewrite_module` :)